# Number of Solutions of the Hyperbola Equations over Finite Fields

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

I have a problem with proving the number of points of the hyperbola equation $H_u: x^2 - y^2 = u$ (for every **u** > 0 in finite field $F_p$) in the finite fields. I have to prove that the number of solutions of the hyperbola equation $H_1: x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is the same as the number of solutions of the equation $H_u$: $x^2 - y^2 = u$ in every finite fields $F_p$, so $|H_1| = |H_u|$.

**For example**:

Equation $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ has 12 solutions in $F_{13}$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 7$ has 12 in $F_{13}$

Equation $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ has 16 solutions in $F_{17}$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 5$ has 12 in $F_{17}$

I have been able to prove that this is true if **u** is a quadratic residue, but I have not been able to prove that if **u** is a quadratic non-residue.

[Picture of my proof of the number of solutions of the hyperbola equation if a is quadratic residue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQUJT.png)

*Can anyone please help me formulate proof by mapping if **u** is a quadratic non-residue for every $u > 0$ in finite field $F_p$ (where p is prime number)? It's also necessary to find the appropriate representation, as I found in the case of quadratic residues, as shown in the figure in the appendix.*

**For example with quadratic residues**:

In finite field $F_{11}: x^2 - y^2 = u$: for u = 1 -> u = 5 ($\alpha = 4$)

(1,0) -> ($4 \cdot 1$, $4\cdot 0$)

(2,5) -> ($4 \cdot 2$, $4\cdot 5$)

(2, 6) -> ($4 \cdot 2$, $4 \cdot 6$)

(4, 2) -> ($4 \cdot 4$, $4 \cdot 2$)

(4, 9) -> ($4 \cdot 4$, $4\cdot 9$)

(7, 2) -> ($4 \cdot 7$, $4\cdot 2$)

(7, 9) -> ($4 \cdot 7$, $4\cdot 9$)

(9, 5) -> ($4 \cdot 9$, $4\cdot 5$)

(9, 6) -> ($4 \cdot 9$, $4\cdot 6$)

(1, 0) -> ($4 \cdot 1$, $4\cdot 0$)

So it means, that for $(x, y) \in H_1: \varphi(x, y) \rightarrow (4x, 4y)$ where $(4x, 4y) \in H_5$ because 5 is **quadratic residue**. I need to find something like this for quadratic non-residue, for example u = 6.

Thanks for help

Comment: If $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution of $x^2+y^2=a$ ($a$ non-zero), the other solutions $Q=(x,y)$ are almost in bijective correspondence with the slope $\lambda$ of the line $PQ$. In other words, $P$ and $\lambda$ determine $Q$. For one choice of $\lambda$ we have $P=Q$. This happens when $\lambda$ is the slope of the tangent of the circle $x^2+y^2=a$ at $P$. Other problematic cases are when $1+\lambda^2=0$ for in those cases plugging the solution of $y$ of the equation of the line $PQ$ into $x^2+y^2=a$ leads to a linear equation in $x$ rather thant the expected quadratic.

Comment: (cont'd) The slope can take value $\lambda=\infty$ in addition to any element of (cont'd) $\Bbb{F}_p$. Anyway, in addition to point $P$ we get either $p$ or $p-2$ other solutions depending on whether $x^2+1=0$ has solutions in $\Bbb{F}_p$ or not. As long as $a\neq0$ it does not matter whether it is a quadratic residue or not. You may have seen this idea used in classifying primitive Pythagorean triples by the slope of the line connecting $(1,0)$ and $(x/z,y/z)$.

Comment: This has probably been explained somewhere on this site already, but it is past midnight here, so I won't look for it right now. Hope you got it anyway.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help, but I found a mistake in my request, the correct equation for hyperbole in finite field is $x^2 - y^2 = a$. I mistakenly wrote an equation for a circle in the finite field (I was wrong + and -). But yes - even in this case it is necessary to find the bijection, unfortunately I managed only for the mentioned quadratic residues (the picture in the appendix also shows the procedure). Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: I replaced the parameter a with the parameter u so that the proof for quadratic residues can be seen according to the picture. I try to formulate a similar proof and representation for quadratic residuals for the equation $x ^ 2 - y ^ 2 = u$.

Comment: The same argument still works, I think. Only this time the exceptional values of $\lambda$ satisfy $1-\lambda^2=0$ so there will always be two exceptional choices. But in the case of $x^2-y^2=a$ a simpler argument comes from the factorization $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$. If $p$ is odd, the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,x-y)$ is a bijection. Surely you see that the number of solutions of $uv=a$ is always $p-1$?

Comment: Yes, if you have equation $x^2 - y^2 = u$, number of solutions is still $p - 1$, if $u > 0 \in F_p$. I have proved it in my thesis. But in mapping $(,) \rightarrow (+,−)$ is missing parameter u or not?

Comment: Because I need mapping $\varphi(x, y) \rightarrow (a, b)$ where $(x, y) \in H_1 \wedge (a, b) \in H_u$

Comment: For example $\varphi(x, y) \rightarrow (u \cdot (x+y)^{-1} + x, u \cdot (x-y)^{-1} + y,)$ in $F_7$, but it works with u = 6 and no with u = 5.

Comment: A hyperbolic equation is a type of partial differential equation. The tag was irrelevant here, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is still not entirely clear to me what kind of a mapping you are looking for. The following will work irrespective of whether $u\neq0$ is a square in $\Bbb{F}_p$ or not:

$$\phi(x,y)=(\frac12[(u+1)x-(u-1)y],\frac12[(u+1)y-(u-1)x]).$$

So here $(x',y')=\phi(x,y)$ satisfies $x'^2-y'^2=u$ if and only if $x^2-y^2=1$, which was the goal as I understood it.

---

This formula is by no means the only possible one. I arrived at it by the following process, the elements of which were explained in the later comments after the circle/hyperbola mix-up was sorted out.

- The mapping $T:\Bbb{F}_p^2\to\Bbb{F}_p^2$, $$T(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$$ is a bijection when $p>2$.
- It has an inverse $T^{-1}:\Bbb{F}_p^2\to\Bbb{F}_p^2$ given by $$T^{-1}(v,w)=(\frac12(v+w),\frac12(v-w)).$$
- The transformation $T$ is relevant here as $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. Meaning that $(v,w)=T(x,y)$ is a solution of $vw=z$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is a solution of $x^2-y^2=z$ (here $z$ is an arbitrary non-zero constant in $\Bbb{F}_p$).
- Then we have the mapping $S:\Bbb{F}_p^2\to\Bbb{F}_p^2$, $$S(v,w)=(v,uw).$$ Its relevance comes from the fact that $(v,w)$ is a solution of $vw=1$ if and only if $S(v,w)=(a,b)$ is a solution of $ab=u$.

My transformation $\phi$ is the composition
$$\phi=T^{-1}\circ S\circ T,$$
and it is hopefully obvious why it works.

---

It may be worth observing that when $u=1$ the mapping $\phi$ is the identity, and when $u=-1$ we get $\phi(x,y)=(y,x)$.

---

Answering the title question is trivial via the invertible transformation $T$. For all $u\in\Bbb{F}_p$, $u\neq0$, the equation $x^2-y^2=u$ has $p-1$ solutions $(x,y)\in\Bbb{F}_p^2$ because the equation $vw=u$ obviusly has $p-1$ solutions $(v,u/v)$, where $v$ is ranging over the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$.